# Exception and Error in powershell

Tags: powershell, error-handling, exception

`try` block throws an exception but in the `catch` block [`Resolve-Error`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/12/07/resolve-error/) method gets `$Error` as null (zero elements in the array), although `$_.Exception` gives me the correct message. What could be the reason and how should I resolve it?

```
function Resolve-Error($ErrorRecord=$Error[0]) {
    $ErrorRecord | Format-List * -Force
    $ErrorRecord.InvocationInfo | Format-List *
    $Exception = $ErrorRecord.Exception
    for ($i = 0; $Exception; $i++, ($Exception = $Exception.InnerException)) {
        "$i" * 80
        $Exception | Format-List * -Force
    }
}

try {
    dsfhjbahdjfb
} catch {
    Write-Host $_.Exception
    if ($_.Exception.Response -ne $null) {
        $result = $_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()
        $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($result)
        $reader.BaseStream.Position = 0
        $reader.DiscardBufferedData()
        $responseBody = $reader.ReadToEnd();
        Write-Host $responseBody
    }
    Resolve-Error
    throw "Exception....."
}
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the behavior you describe. How did you conclude that `$Error` was empty?

Comment: The `Resolve-Error` call in the `catch` block should be throwing an error itself, because the function is not yet defined at that point.

Comment: Try catch block is inside another function. That function and Resolve-Error are part of a powershell module. First I do Import-Module and then just debug. So Resolve-Error is already defined.

Comment: Even with the placement of the function definition corrected the code you posted does not expose the behavior you describe. Please update your question with a [mcve] that allows us to actually reproduce and analyze the behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure why but passing exception($_) as input paramater to  Resolve-Error worked for me.